# How can I draw Hyperbolic functions

Tags: pgfplots

Ho can I draw hyperbolic functions in latex
I use follow code, but it's false and I don't know why?

```
\begin{figure}[H]‎
‎\begin{center}‎
‎\scalebox{.7}{‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-5:5, samples=500, axis lines*=middle, ytick={1.57,-1.57},,xtick={10} yticklabels={‎$‎\pi‎$/2‎,-$\pi$/2}]
    \addplot[color=black, very thick‎]  {sinh(x)/180*pi};‎
\node at (2,1.5) {\footnotesize $y=‎\sinh ‎(x)‎$};‎
      \end{axis}
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎ }
‎\end{center}‎
‎\end{figure‏}‎‎‎‎
```

and same as for cosh, tanh, coth, csch, sech.

Comment: Place a comma between the options `xtick={10}` and  `yticklabels={‎$‎\pi‎$/2‎,-$\pi$/2}` and remove the many (invisible) LTR marks (U+200E) from your code. It should compile fine then.

Comment: What are 180 and pi doing there?

Answer (score 6):

When I complete your code snippet to a compilable MWE, I get as the first error:
`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/very thick‎' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

This error at first sight seems to be very strange, because the key `tikz/very thick` actually exists. However, if you look more closely at the codepoints of the string, you will observe, that there is an invisible character after `thick`, namely U+200E "LTR mark":

```
/    t    i    k    z    /    v    e    r    y         t    h    i    c    k    ‎
002f 0074 0069 006b 007a 002f 0076 0065 0072 0079 0020 0074 0068 0069 0063 006b 200e
```

In fact, there are even more instances of this character in your code snippet. When U+200E is replaced by •, your code snippet looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]•
•\begin{center}•
•\scalebox{.7}{•
•\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-5:5, samples=500, axis lines*=middle, ytick={1.57,-1.57},,xtick={10} yticklabels={•$•\pi•$/2•,-$\pi$/2}]
    \addplot[color=black, very thick•]  {sinh(x)/180*pi};‎
\node at (2,1.5) {\footnotesize $y=•\sinh •(x)•$};•
      \end{axis}
•\end{tikzpicture}• }
•\end{center}•
•\end{figure•}••••
```

In most positions, this is actually not critical. But at least `very thick•` and `\end{figure•}` will cause parsing errors. So, the first thing to do should be to delete all these invisible characters.

Now, having cleaned up the code so far, you should still get an error, because there is a comma missing between the two options `xtick={10}` and `yticklabels={$\pi$/2,-$\pi$/2}`.

Having fixed this as well, you will get the following output without errors:

[image]

With a properly formatted MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\scalebox{.7}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-5:5, samples=500, axis lines*=middle, ytick={1.57,-1.57}, xtick={10}, yticklabels={$\pi$/2,-$\pi$/2}]
    \addplot[color=black, very thick] {sinh(x)/180*pi};
    \node at (2,1.5) {\footnotesize $y=\sinh(x)$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I don't know if you really need to place the diagram inside a `\begin{figure}[H]`. Maybe it is also enough just to place it into the document as is. Also, I would probably not use `\scalebox`. But this is for you to decide, of course.

Comment: Strange your output of sinh (x): see the graph here https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7bbbdc7447b924b599be6db324c9dd9b.webp

Comment: @Sebastiano Right. In fact, I did not really focus on whether the output of the plot makes sense, but on why the code produced errors.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    domain=-5.0:5.0,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ]
\addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick,samples=400] {sinh(\x)};
\node [right, red] at (axis cs: 1.5,.8) {$y = \sinh x$};
\draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:-2,-3.0)-- (axis cs:-2,0);
\draw [blue, dotted, thick] (axis cs:+2,+3.0)-- (axis cs:+2,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-.5, ymax=5,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    domain=-5.0:5.0,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ]
\addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick,samples=400] {cosh(\x)};
\node [right, red] at (axis cs: .5,.8) {$y = \cosh x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    domain=-5.0:5.0,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ]
\addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick,samples=400] {tanh(\x)};
\node [right, red] at (axis cs: .8,.5) {$y = \tanh x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]